# Facebook Application Privacy policy

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

A web appliction is running on my local machine (can't be accessible from Internet, it is a developer site, not the production one), e.g. URL:1 http://myapp.com.

I want to configure a Facebook app on my web application. Created  Facebook application, App > App Details, at Privacy Policy URL given URL:1 this message appeared:

> "You must submit a valid Privacy Policy URL in order to be compliant with Facebook Platform. Request failed with error: Can't Download: Could not resolve the hostname into a valid IP address."

My application is a development site. I can't expose it on a public domain. I don't have Privacy Policy URL on public domain. What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be accessible and public. You can´t enter a link that only runs on your local machine, Facebook obviously can´t check if it´s there.

Comment: yes The valid URL's are checked if they can be scraped , I tested from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ as the URL i given is on private domain, its not able to scrap.

I don't have any public domain to host. as its a developers site, not the production one.

does Facebook have a different mode to deal for developers,How developers need to proceed?

Comment: no, you have to put the policy on a server, that´s the only way.